# Let me scroll you - How do I add scroll bar to Git Bash

Tags: cmd, git-bash

So I'm using Git Bash. And I seriously want to be able to scroll back. I've tried adding the `Quick Edit` function, but nothing no scroll bar.

All I want is to scroll...

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How do I add scroll bar to Git Bash?

1. Click on the icon image at the top left of the Git Bash window
2. Select Properties
3. Select the Layout tab.
4. Set the Screen Buffer Size Height to a larger number than
   the Window Size Height.

Scroll bars will only appear if the buffer size is larger than the window size.

Example settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a simpler solution, but conemu: https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/
has scroll bars and a lot more features.

Answer (score 0):

Shift Up
Shift Down
will do scrolling in git bash